# Formato de fecha estandar sin importar la configuración del dispositivo

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, date, xamarin

Estoy trabajando unas operaciones con fechas (comparación usualmente), entonces lo que hago es tomar la fecha que la base de datos me devuelve en string y convertirla en una fecha con tipo estándar `dd/MM/yyyy`, y compararla con la hora del servidor `dd/MM/yyyy`.

El problema esta en que según el dispositivo y la configuración del usuario, el formato de la fecha varia en lo que es:

`A. M. - a. m.` | `P. M. - p. m.`

**Un simple `Replace` haría el truco pero es que en algunos funciona con mayúsculas, en otros con minúsculas (en unos da error en otros no).**

Para convertirla a una fecha estándar utilizo este método:

```
DateTime TiempoFechaDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(FechaAConvertir, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Error:

> Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Prueba quitando del formato la parte que dice "tt" de la fecha

Comment: Otra cosa, el string que guardas en la bd lo guardas por ej 23/01/1993 12:37 pm, es decir el mismo formato al que intentas convertir o solo guardas 23/01/1993

Comment: @Japv -- De momento lo guardo de esta forma:  -- 6/24/2021 9:13:56 PM -- Pero el workaround de quitarle el AM/PM suena sencillo y practico. Lo pruebo y te dejo saber.